# adb backup aborts with timeout on samsung s10+

Tags: android, adb, backup, samsung-galaxy

I tried to do a backup of the storage of my Samsung S10+ by the adb backup command:
adb backup -shared.
The backup starts and file size increases until about 4.8 GB.
Then there is a message on the phone display (after 10 minutes or so) that says:
Timeout. Operation aborted.

Anyone knows how and where to increase the timeout? Thx

I tried several options on the s10+ with no effect. I searched the web but did not found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you have RealCalc installed, it was the place my backup would timeout.  I uninstalled, and backup completed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).